# Write permissions after checkout completed?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a store that uses Firebase to store the inventory and prices. There isn't any login to the site, but I need the site to update the inventory after a checkout is made, without giving the user access to modify the prices. How would I go about this?

I was thinking about automatically authenticating into a public user account after checkout to update the inventory, but I don't think storing the username and password in a JavaScript file would be very safe.

Answer (score 0):

I agree about just storing authentication data. 
It is pretty simple to add auth stage, just add a sign-in button to make price changes:

```
signInButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
}
```

Listen to changes:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
```

and act:

```
function onAuthStateChanged(user) {...}
```